# Replace Multiple Strings in a SQL File using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am able to replace a single string in a SQL file using PowerShell as follows:

```
$newPrefix = "foo'
$dbUserMappingScriptPath = "C:\MySQL_Template.sql"
$updatedDbUserMapingScriptPath = "C:\MySQL.sql"
(gc $dbUserMappingScriptPath).Replace('DBPrefix_',$newPrefix) | sc $updatedDbUserMapingScriptPath
```

This is great for single scenarios, but I need to replace multiple strings. I have tried the following, but it doesn't perform the replace operation beyond replacing the first string of 'DBPrefix_' with $newPrefix. It does not perform the replacements for 'MDFDatabasePath' and 'LDFDatabasePath'.

How do I replace multiple strings given the following snippet? Note that this is wrapped in a Foreach-Object for the $*.MDFDatabasePath and $*.LDFDatabasePath values.

```
$dbUserMappingScriptPath = "C:\MySQL_Template.sql"
$updatedDbUserMapingScriptPath = "C:\MySQL.sql"
(gc $dbUserMappingScriptPath).Replace('DBPrefix_',$newPrefix).Replace('MDFDatabasePath',$_.MDFDatabasePath).Replace('LDFDatabasePath',$_.LDFDatabasePath) | sc $updatedDbUserMapingScriptPath
```

Here is a snippet of my SQL:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DBPrefix_mydb] ON 
( FILENAME = N'MDFDatabasePath\DBPrefix_mydb.MDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'LDFDatabasePath\DBPrefix_mydb.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

**UPDATE:** I had a mismatch in my PowerShell script in that I was running the replace on the wrong SQL script. The code above with an extra .Replace works like a charm

Comment: This should work. You should try to print the text after the first replace and ensure `MDFDatabasePath` is within your text. Also print out `$_.MDFDatabasePath` to ensure the variable is set.

Comment: MDFDatabasePath is in the text. Will check the variable setting soon

Comment: I tried hard coding a value and it failed to replace. Ex ('MDFDatabasePath','c:/SQL')

Comment: hm. can you post an reproducable example (content of `$dbUserMappingScriptPath`)

Comment: Updated with a snippet of the SQL.Of note is that the first replace of DBPrefix works

Comment: Disregard, I had a mismatch in my script in that I was running the replace on the wrong SQL file

Comment: thougth. becacue your example worked for me as well.